# Excel - With mutiple criteria (Index/Match) show multiple results in colums next to eachother?

Tags: excel

In M39 I have a MATCH/INDEX Formula with multiple criteria that searches for the result on another sheet and in N39 I have a Textjoin formula that shows all the results of M39. I either need a formula that displays all the INDEX/MATCH results in columns next to each other or a way to separete all the results in a Textjoin column of N39?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tf83.png (MATCH/INDEX)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nE5K.png (TEXTJOIN CELL)

Comment: Having some example data of what it currently looks like, as well the expected output would be helpful. Which version of Office are you dealing with, as most office 365 versions will output arrays. As for the text join, you could just use concat()

Comment: Use `FILTER()` function which will automatically show results in individual columns.

Comment: Filter function with a transpose to get all the data horizontally, should work better, thank you Harun24HR!